# Bigquery for curve shape matching

Tags: pattern-matching, google-bigquery

I got a lot of raw data from a sensor network and different shapes represent different events.
I think Google Bigquery is the good way to handle the vast data coming from the sensors.  But I don't know how to find the matching shape.[image: sensor data]

Here is an example: the red squared as the shape template. I like to use this template to find all similar shapes in the given dataset. Bigquery's corr() should be the solution but it needs fixed comparing windows.

Oracle's SQL pattern matching (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17749/pattern.htm#DWHSG8956) is more close to what I want but I still like to stay with the Bigquery for the integration with GAE and other Googler service.

Does anyone knows how to handle this situation? Thanks a lot.

=============
Raw data from the sensors:
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1wRJCgCo74uY0N5ZWk4QlVYLVE/edit?usp=sharing)

sample rate: 1Hz; 
compressed: to save the storage, the sensor only saves the data different from last saved data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ready for some magic? It's not the most clear query I've written, but it seems to be working.

So I'm looking for this shape:

[image]

And I'll build the equivalent with a query:

```
SELECT r, x 
FROM  (SELECT 1 r, 90 x),
      (SELECT 2 r, 90 x),
      (SELECT 3 r, 0 x),
      (SELECT 4 r, 10 x),
      (SELECT 5 r, 20 x);
```

Now, with a single query I'll move that shape over the full dataset, measuring correlation. The query will sort all results and will tell me where in time we have the 5 consecutive points that most resemble that shape:

```
SELECT CORR(a.x, b.Pressure) corr, d5, COUNT(*) c
FROM (
  SELECT INTEGER(r) r, x FROM 
  (SELECT 1 r, 90 x), (SELECT 2 r, 90 x), (SELECT 3 r, 0 x), (SELECT 4 r, 10 x), (SELECT 5 r, 20 x)
  ) a
JOIN EACH (
  SELECT a.DateTime d0, b.d5 d5, a.Pressure pressure,
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY d5 ORDER BY d0) r
  FROM [seventh-helix-483:waterpressure.pressue_1391719236611] a
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DateTime, LEAD(DateTime, 4) OVER(ORDER BY DateTime) d5
    FROM [seventh-helix-483:waterpressure.pressue_1391719236611]) b
  WHERE a.DateTime BETWEEN b.DateTime AND b.d5) b
ON a.r=b.r
GROUP BY d5
HAVING c=5
ORDER BY corr DESC
LIMIT 5
```

And the results are in:

```
corr                d5                  c    
0.9998464758523021  1/27/2014 21:04:07  5    
0.9980241522460084  1/28/2014 20:25:20  5    
0.9978582480606312  1/27/2014 19:27:36  5    
0.9972145139280599  1/29/2014 23:00:07  5    
0.9961191863441274  1/30/2014 12:11:08  5
```

(using data from https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/seventh-helix-483:waterpressure.pressue_1391719236611)

Comment: Great! this should be the way to find the matching! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of using CORR(). How about doing it within a temporal CROSS JOIN?

If you share some data I can take a stab at writing the query.

Comment: Thanks Fh, I was inspired by your post [link] (http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2013/09/introducing-corr-to-google-bigquery.html) and I think using corr() is much better than writing multiple filers for template matching. I already update the data to bigquery (not public) and could you send me your email  so I can share all the detail data. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you share some sample data publicly? I'm very interested in this use case, but when I spend time solving some queries, I really like being able to share the results later :)

Comment: Sure, please check the original question and I added the link for the raw data from the sensors. Please let me know if you need anything else. Thanks for your help.

Comment: sorry for not replying yet! (hectic days here) - my next step is to take the csv and upload it to BQ, but it would be easier if you share the data already loaded into bigquery (create a new dataset, put just the sample data there, and share with everyone)

Comment: It's shared now. "seventh-helix-483:waterpressure.pressue_1391719236611"   BTW: I didn't add the ignored data (if no value change, the sensor doesn't save it.) We are only interested in the shapes/slopes, it should be OK. Let me know if anything else you need. Thanks ; )